# object problems in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I create object and put in on array so I can use it multiple time I tried like this

```
var createNew = new enemyMove(id);
```

So every Time I use it Iwill have a different values and fields

```
function enemyMove() {


    var enemyimagew = document.getElementById("enemy");
    var leftenemy = parseInt(enemyimagew.style.left);
    var topenemy = parseInt(enemyimagew.style.top);


        if (leftenemy < leftplayer) {
            leftenemy = leftenemy + 5;

        }
        if (leftenemy > leftplayer) {
            leftenemy = leftenemy - 5;

        }

        if (topenemy < topplayer) {
            topenemy = topenemy + 5;
        }
        if (topenemy > topplayer) {
            topenemy = topenemy - 5;
        }

        enemyimagew.style.left = leftenemy + "px";
        enemyimagew.style.top = topenemy + "px";

        var hit_list = $("#x").collision(".lollol");
        hit_list.remove();   
}

function enemyMovetow() {


    var enemyimage = document.getElementById("enemy2");
    var leftenemy = parseInt(enemyimage.style.left);
    var topenemy = parseInt(enemyimage.style.top);


    if (leftenemy < leftplayer) {
        leftenemy = leftenemy + 5;

    }
    if (leftenemy > leftplayer) {
        leftenemy = leftenemy - 5;

    }

    if (topenemy < topplayer) {
        topenemy = topenemy + 5;
    }
    if (topenemy > topplayer) {
        topenemy = topenemy - 5;
    }

    enemyimage.style.left = leftenemy + "px";
    enemyimage.style.top = topenemy + "px";

    var hit_list = $("#x").collision(".lollol");
    hit_list.remove();
}
```

I want this 2 functions on an array so I wont write another one

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve. A user-story in pseudocode, if needed.

Comment: It sounds like you want some kind of factory method that produces instances of `enemyMove` randomly initialized. Is that want you mean?

Comment: What you're doing, essentially, is calling the constructor `enemyMove` but I do not see that code anywhere.  Does it exist?

Comment: Sometimes questions on Stackoverflow are like puzzles.

Comment: @dfsq Yup.  You are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
var enemies = [
    new enemyMove(id), new ememyMove(id + 1), new enemyMove(id + 2), // ...
];
```

If you clarify more I can help you further.

Comment: Instead of mankin alot of function that has the same properties I just want it on an array..

Comment: @rodolfonavalon But what constitutes them having the same properties? Is it their ID?

Comment: Yea BTW the id is the elementID of img so when the enemy image collied with player image it will be remove from the div box so I created the remove() but the thing is it stops everytime one enemy collieds with the player I dont know why

Comment: You're asking a whole other question here. You should re-ask it in a clear succinct format so you will get the most help as possible. You said you needed the objects in an array and that's what I did for you here in my answer.